# Set string on SweetAlert Box text property without quotation marks

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I am using SweetAlert Box and I have a drop down list on it and in which i need to bind dropdown values dynamically from the code, I am generating code for the values 'list' and setting it to text property but its wrapping in quotes which i need to remove in order to show my dropdownlist values. Its showing empty list because its taking list inside quotation marks. Please help

```
swal({
      title: "",
      text: 'Please select User'+
      ' <select id="ddlUser" >' +
            list + // This list is a variable which has option values for dropdownlist   
      '</select> ',
      html: true,            
});
```

//list has this concatenated data in this form:

```
<option value= "1"> A </option><option value= "2"> B </option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the double quotes with the entity representation, `&quot;`

```
list = '<option value="1"> Option 1 </option>';
list.replace(/"/g, '&quot;');

swal({
    title: "",
    text: 'Please select User'+
    ' <select id="ddlUser" >' +
    list + 
    '</select> ',
     html: true
});
```

Comment: Its still wrapping in quotes, I just need to stop wrapping quotes  not from the whole string because i need to have quotes around value field.